# Call to a member function lists() on null

Tags: php, laravel

When I want to edit a post I'm getting an error.
This is the code from the line where the error is:

```
public function getTagListAttribute()
{
    return $this->tags->lists('id')->all();
}
```

It works perfectly when I read the full post but when I want to edit it I get thrown this error: `Call to a member function lists() on null`

I have also categories code:

```
public function getCategoryListAttribute()
{
    return $this->categories->lists('id')->all();
}
```

And I can edit fine categories but not tags, and they're made the same principal.

Comment: this probably means that your $this -> tags is null or undefined

Comment: var dump $this->tags and check it

Comment: Make sure `$this->tags` contains a query builder, not a collection.

Comment: That should probably be `$this->tags()` to ensure you get a query builder, as Stuart said.