# Call to a member function lists() on null in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 5.3, I am trying to edit registered users in the All Users page (admin/users) and assign roles and permissions to them. I used the codes from laravel 5.2 pdf book. but anytime i click on a user to edit it. It brings up below error

> FatalThrowableError in UsersController.php line 26: Call to a member
>   function lists() on null.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
    $roles = Role::all();
    $selectedRoles = $user->roles->lists('id')->toArray();
    return view('backend.users.edit', compact('user', 'roles', 'selectedRoles'));
}
```

Comment: Can You show us Your `roles` method inside `User` class?

Comment: check [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745597/call-to-a-member-function-lists-on-null?rq=1). Although, there are no answers there. But, comments may be helpful.

Comment: i used entrust for my roles and permission.

Answer (score 4):

The `lists()` function has been discontinued since Laravel 5.3. You should use `pluck` instead.

```
$selectedRoles = $user->roles->pluck('id');
```

Regarding the error:
You must not be having any roles for a particular user, hence the error.

Comment: i replaced lists with pluck, but the same error pops up. and i dont understand what you mean by not having any roles for a particular user

Comment: Check the database records. Else go to `tinker` and type `$user->roles` for all the users you have in the system. You will get some user(s) that do not have any roles.

Comment: tinker is not working. it brings out undefined variable: user in line 1

Comment: There's no problem with `tinker`. You first need to get a `User` object with `$user = App\User::find(<user id>)`. I suggest you watch some Laravel videos on Laracasts.

Answer (score 0):

add below code in

> app/User.php

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

After that use bellow code in

> Http/Controllers/UserController.php

```
$userRole = $user->roles()->lists('id','id')->toArray();
```

Instead of

```
$userRole = $user->roles->lists('id','id')->toArray();
```